# Defining Javascript's object property by invoking function

Tags: javascript, properties, javascript-objects

Suppose I have a javascript Object and I want to define a property and property attributes for it. i.e I want to define scaleRatio through a function. How would I go about this ?

I know I can do `canvasData.scaleRatio = function(){};`

Do I then define `Object.defineProperty{canvasData, 'scaleRatio', {enumerable: true, configurable: false};` ?

Is there a systematic way of defining properties and attributes directly on an object ? I know you can do set: function(){} inside defineProperty but I don't want to do that extra step canvasData.scaleRatio = 'asdf'; Why can't I just use an iffe inside object.defineProperty ?

**Update:**

**My reasoning for this is that I want to call setupCanvas and initialize a CanvasObject and all it's properties.  Some of it's properties will have to be computed by calling a function. I also want to be able to specify property attributes. How can I do this in a systematic way ?**

```
function setupCanvas(chart){
    canvasData = Object.defineProperties({}, {
        scaleRatio: {
                value: function(){
                    console.log('gets here');
                    var ratio = chart.data.datasets[0].data.reduce(function(prev,curr){
                    if (prev > curr){
                        return prev; 
                    }
                    return curr; 
                });
                return $(canvas).outerWidth() / (scaleRatio + 10);      
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: false,
            writable: true
        }
    });
    console.log(canvasData.scaleRatio);,
}
```

Comment: Can't tell what you're really asking here.  Are you just trying to define a getter (a regular readable property who's value is returned from a function).

Comment: "*Why can't I just use an iffe inside object.defineProperty ?*" - But you can?

Comment: @jfriend00. Sorry for the confusion. Wont a getter do this computation every time ? I want to directly assign the return value of my function to the scaleRatio when I am assigning it's attributes.

Comment: Then, I'm really confused what you're asking.  Why not just assign to the scaleRatio property then?  No need for `defineProperty()` if you're just assigning a property value.

Comment: @jfriend00 I get that but what if I want to set the attributes at the same time. ?

Comment: What does at the same time mean?  Set one on one line of code and another on the next line of code.  Or, you can use `defineProperty()` to just set a value if you want (though I don't know why you'd bother).  It sure sounds like you're making this problem a lot more complex than it needs to be `obj.scaleRatio = xxx`.

Comment: @jfriend00 by the same time i mean Object.defineProperty({}, scaleRatio,{value: function(), enumerable: true, configurable: false, writable: true}); so I can set the property and attribute at the same time. Then i can do canvasData.scaleRatio and get my value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I just use an iffe inside object.defineProperty ?

You can put an IIFE in place of the value.  Here's an example of the proper syntax to do that:

```js
var canvasData = Object.defineProperties({}, {
    scaleRatio: {
        value: (function(){
            // put whatever logic you want here
            return Math.random();
        })(),
        writable: true,
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true
    }
});

console.log(canvasData);
console.log(canvasData.scaleRatio);
```

The `value` function you show in your code example is not an IIFE - it's just a regular function so you're create a `scaleRatio` property that is a method, not a static property.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Out of curiosity is this a bad design principle ? I am trying to encapsulate these methods inside the object so it is not callable by other functions.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi - Nothing wrong with using an IIFE in that circumstance.  It does serve the purpose of encapsulating and hiding the code so nobody else can get at the function.